# Can you annotate classes that are not defined with the ES6 class keyword with Facebook's Flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, flowtype

I have a lot of legacy ES5 code that does not use the class keyword to define "classes". I would like to annotate and do type checking with Flow. Is that possible?

I've only found examples that use the class keyword:
https://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ES5 "classes" are just functions you can most certainly add type annotations for many of the same checks

e.g. this ES6 Class deinition with Flow

```
class Hello {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  hello(): string {
    return 'Hello ' + this.name + '!';
  }

  static sayHelloAll(): string {
    return 'Hello everyone!';
  }
}
```

could be written like this:

```
function Hello(name: string) {
  this.name = name;
}

Hello.prototype.hello = function hello(): string {
  return 'Hello ' + this.name + '!';
};

Hello.sayHelloAll = function (): string {
  return 'Hello everyone!';
};
```

though you do miss the extra class property check on name.

More pertinent to your question I suspect, it seems you can check other variables/arguments etc to see if they match your ES5 "Class" by using the constructor function name as a type annotation:

https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#constructor-functions-and-prototype-objects

EDIT: Yeah I just tried naively adding an annotation like this:

```
this.name: string = name;
```

but flowtype doesn't currently like that.
Unless someone knows better I guess the only workaround is something like

```
const tmpName: string = name;
this.name = tmpName;
```

though this is obviously not great.

Comment: ```though you do miss the extra class property check on name.```
That's what I was trying to figure out how to do :)